# how to query postgresql database via salt

Tags: postgresql, saltstack

I need to run a query on a postgresql database in a module I'm writing for Salt. It won't do much, just query a table for a value to determine what version of the software is installed.

The [docs](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.postgres.html#module-salt.modules.postgres) have a `psql_query` function but you can't specify the database, so I'm guessing the query is run against the maintenance db.

To confound things, the postgresql module docs say I have to specify connection params in the minion config, which means having to manually create the postgresql user or duplicating configuration unless the minion config can read from pillar data (pretty sure it can't).

Now, the [mysql module](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.mysql.html#salt.modules.mysql.query) for salt *does* have the exact interface I need in the `query` function.

The inability to query a psql db seems like such an egregious oversight that its probably me misunderstanding something. Ordinarily I would dive into the code and figure out what is going, but there is so much magic I don't know where to begin. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Found the code (Google wasn't revealing it) and it simply doesn't exist. I've raised this as a feature request [here](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/16319) and am inspecting the code to see if I can contribute.

Salt is amazing but it still has lots of these little gaps.

**UPDATE**: after going through the code you *can* specify the database with the parameter `maintenance_db`, which is misleading because that has a specific meaning. An example usage might be:

```
postgres.psql_query query='select * from foo' maintenance_db='dbname' user='username' password='password'
```